# Subtract successive rows in a dataframe grouped by id

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
id        day           total_amount
 1       2015-07-09         1000
 1       2015-10-22          100
 1       2015-11-12          200
 1       2015-11-27         2392
 1       2015-12-16          123
 6       2015-07-09          200
 7       2015-07-09         1000
 7       2015-08-27       100018
 7       2015-11-25         1000
 8       2015-08-27         1000
 8       2015-12-07        10000
 8       2016-01-18          796
 8       2016-03-31        10000
15       2015-09-10         1500
15       2015-09-30         1000
```

I need to subtract every two successive time in day column if they have the same id until reaching the last row of that id then start subtracting times in day column this time for new id, something similar to following lines in output is expected:

```
7 2015-07-09         1000  2015-08-27 - 2015-07-09
7 2015-08-27       100018  2015-07-09 - 2015-08-27
7 2015-07-09         1000            0
8 2015-08-27         1000  2015-12-07 - 2015-08-27
8 2015-12-07        10000  2016-01-18 - 2015-12-07
8 2016-01-18          796  2016-03-31 - 2016-01-18 
8 2016-03-31        10000            0
15 2015-09-10         1000 2015-09-30 - 2015-09-10
15 2015-09-30         1000 2015-10-01 - 2015-09-30
15 2015-10-01         1000
```

Comment: Read about [dplyr: lead and lag](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html)

Comment: In which format do you want your output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the difference as number of days you could try:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, id) %>% mutate(new = as.Date(lead(day)) - as.Date(day))
Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: id [5]

      id        day total_amount      new
   (int)     (fctr)        (int)   (dfft)
1      1 2015-07-09         1000 105 days
2      1 2015-10-22          100  21 days
3      1 2015-11-12          200  15 days
4      1 2015-11-27         2392  19 days
5      1 2015-12-16          123  NA days
6      6 2015-07-09          200  NA days
7      7 2015-07-09         1000  49 days
8      7 2015-08-27       100018  90 days
9      7 2015-11-25         1000  NA days
10     8 2015-08-27         1000 102 days
11     8 2015-12-07        10000  42 days
12     8 2016-01-18          796  73 days
13     8 2016-03-31        10000  NA days
14    15 2015-09-10         1500  20 days
15    15 2015-09-30         1000  NA days
```

**EDITED**

To subtract the last date from the current date you can use:

```
# First save the above result as `df1`:
df1[is.na(df1["new"]), "new"] <- as.Date(unlist(df1[is.na(df1["new"]), "day"]))
     - Sys.Date()
```

Comment: what if i want to subtract the the time in last row of an id from current time? for example instead of NA in row 5 , put  (current time - 2015-12-16)?

Comment: @sanaz Sorry for the dalyed reply... I don't quite understand how you mean it. If you subtract the last time from itself you will get 0, as difference between identical dates is zero....

Comment: not subtract from itself but from the current time, for example if today is 2016-05.10 for row 5 i would like to subtract (2016-05.10) - (2015-12-16)